# c++ use thread as timer

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

I have my project with a different thread that make some stuff.

It's all ok, but I wish have some function called each 20ms (for example), but considering the time spent to the function... I try to explain better... I call the function, and the function spent 6ms to exit, so I wish that the thread sleeps 14ms (20 - 6), the next time that is called, the function spent 12ms, so the sleep will be only 8ms....
how can I do this?
here is my code:

```
// thread constructor
DWORD dwThreadId, dwThrdParam = 1;  
HANDLE thread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)workerFunc, &dwThrdParam, 0, &dwThreadId );

// thread function
DWORD WINAPI workerFunc( LPDWORD lpdwParam )
{
    while( true )
    {
        myFunction( );
        Sleep( ??? );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: i think before entering get system time, after returning get system time too, subtract them then sleep 20 - result. it would be an approximation since you will lose time calculating how much you should wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
clock_t start, end;
while( true )
{
    start = clock();
    myFunction( );
    end = clock();
    Sleep(20-(end-start)*CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000.0);
}
```

Comment: +1, But might need a crash guard if end-start > 20, since Sleep expects an unsigned int (http://preview.tinyurl.com/5uydxea)

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to send the thread to sleep for a variable amount of time:

```
void periodic_function()
{
  /* function body */

  timestamp = get_time(); // pseudo-function
  remaining_sleep_time = std::min(0, 20 - (timestamp - last_timestamp));
  last_timestamp = timestamp;
  milli_sleep_callback(remaining_sleep_time, periodic_function);
}
```

You'll need a suitable steady clock function for `get_time()` and a sleep function - try the `<chrono>` or `<tr1/chrono>` header. In this example I've assumed that you have a timer callback (like in boost.ASIO), but you could also make an infinite loop or something like that.

This function will work if the function body never exceeds 20ms, though it'll do a quick catch-up if your function ever takes *longer*. If you want to synchronize to a global 20ms rhythm, you'd have to add another global step counter or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before calling `myFunc` and after calling `myFunc`. The difference gives you the time spent in `myFunc`. Note that this time includes the time spent by the process due to OS scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

If you need precision, use `NtSetTimerResolution` when program starts up to set timer resolution. Yes, it is undocumented function, but works well. You may also use `NtQueryTimerResolution` to know timer-resolution (before setting and after setting new resolution to be sure).

You need to dynamically get the address of these functions using `GetProcAddress` from `NTDLL.DLL`, as it is not declared in header or any LIB file.

Setting timer resolution this way would affect `Sleep`, Windows timers, functions that return current time etc.