# How can you start time counting in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, time.h

does anybody know of a function or library that starts counting time.
Because I'm working on a project that needs to count time for an event to happen.

Pseudo code

```
start time
if ( seconds % 2 == 0 )
{
    counter++

}
```

I chose 2 seconds because it's a nice number

Comment: Timers are typically implemented through calls to the OS, as the machine you're running on is what is actually keeping any type of "time" whatsoever. We would need to know what machine you're using (though I assume C++ on a windows machine?). Take a look at the MSDN.

Comment: yeah I'm using a windows computer.

Comment: Visit the MSDN that microsoft provides. They have information on a lot of API functions, and timers are among them.

Answer (score 1):

Typically periodic event generation is done using a separate thread which uses an operating system call to use the operating system timer services in order to provide a reasonably accurate timer event.  The separate thread will schedule the timer event and wait for the timer to expire at which point the thread wakes and begins execution.  Once the work is done, a new timer event is scheduled.

However if a great deal of accuracy is not needed you could take the approach of a thread that performs a wait for a given number of milliseconds and then issues an event and then loops back around to do the timed wait or sleep again.

The most important part of this is usually that you must have what ever is doing the waiting to be another thread so that the main thread is not blocked.  The idea is to have a working thread which acts as a generator of events while your main thread and any other threads are processing their own events such as user interface events.

See [C++ use thread as timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732238/c-use-thread-as-timer).

Also this [codeproject Threads and Timers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5958/Threads-And-Timers).